# Add tag to locked question

Tags: discussion, support

The following question is the [top listed Frequest question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Frequent):

[Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

However, this question has not version tag - so it is not clear to users if it refers to Magento 1 or Magento 2. **Please add a `magento-1` tag to the question so that it will be obvious to readers that the answers do not apply to current Magento versions.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. Thanks for pointing it out